# How do I use bulk insert to import a file just based on its file extension?

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, bulkinsert

I have a folder that new log files get created every hour.  Each time the file name is different. How do I bulk insert just based on any file that has the extension .log? Here is my code

```
select * from [data_MaximusImport_t]
BULK
INSERT Data_MaximusImport_t
FROM 'C:\Program Files (x86)\DataMaxx\*.log'
WITH
(FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

Right now I get the error *.log" could not be opened. Operating system error code 123(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.).

***this is an edit to my original question. I was able to figure out the file name with this code

```
DECLARE @Path varchar(256) = 'dir C:\datamaxx\*.log'
DECLARE @Command varchar(1024) =  @Path + ' /A-D  /B'
INSERT INTO myFileList
EXEC MASTER.dbo.xp_cmdshell @Command
SELECT * FROM myFileList
```

Now i just need to figure out how to stick that name in the path.  SHould i delcare the file name as a variable?

Comment: BULK INSERT does not support a wildcard in the filename parameter

Comment: How is your SQL being called? Is this a sproc called by SQL Agent, or is this SQL from another program? If so, use the external program to iterate through each file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need dynamic SQL for this.

Assuming that the file names are already in `myFileList`, then this is how I would do it:

```
DECLARE @sql As VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = '';

SELECT @sql = @sql + REPLACE('
    BULK INSERT Data_MaximusImport_t
    FROM ''C:\Program Files (x86)\DataMaxx\*''
    WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'' );
    ', '*', myFileName) 
FROM    myFileList
WHERE   myfileName != '';

PRINT @sql;
EXEC(@sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You unfortunately can't use wild cards in the file path with SQL server bulk inserts.

Possible workarounds are scripting a loop to get the filenames from the system and inserting one at a time, or using [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/cc511477.aspx)